# Replace names of Countries using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am working on a pandas dataframe where I want to replace names of the some countries with other name.
Here is the list of the names of the countries I want to replace,

"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"

I had use pandas.DataFrame.replace in my code,
here is code snnipet

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def answer_one():
    energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',skip_footer=38, skiprows=17,parse_cols='C:F')
    cols=['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
    energy.columns=cols
    energy[energy['Energy Supply'] == "..."]=np.NaN
    energy[['Energy Supply','Energy Supply per Capita']]=energy[['Energy Supply','Energy Supply per Capita']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    energy['Energy Supply']=energy['Energy Supply']*10**6
    replace_dict={"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
                  "United States of America": "United States",
                  "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
                  "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}
    energy['Country'].replace(to_replace=replace_dict, inplace=True)
    energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.extract('(^[a-zA-Z\s]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
    print(energy)

    return "ANSWER"
answer_one()
```

But the above code is not working .
Here is the .xls file i'm working on :
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NVlu5IV_8g2SlxCHg5y2coMJ9Tw8jbtWc6_ItJkuXU/edit#gid=1525168449&range=J4) 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) is what you need:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].map(replace_dict)
```

Comment: Its not working ,instead it replace the names of all other countries with NaN